# JSF2 post fails on Glassfish Virtual Server

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish-3

**UPDATE 1**

The problem seems to be with jsf2 placing **two slashes** at the begging of the action attribute of the form:

```
<form id="j_idt16" name="j_idt16" method="post" action="//views/publico/Consulta.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" style="text-align: left">...
```

When deleting of the slashes the application works fine:

```
<form id="j_idt16" name="j_idt16" method="post" action="/views/publico/Consulta.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" style="text-align: left">...
```

**UPDATE 2**

This problem was caused by a misconfiguration in web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>/views/publico/Consulta.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The welcome file should not start with a slash.

I removed it and it's working again.

Comment: This problem was caused by a misconfiguration of my web.xml file.